# Запуск скрипта node одной командой

Tags: node.js

Извините за возможно тупой вопрос, проблему, но я не понимаю)

Сейчас я скрипт запускаю следующем образом

```
node script.js
```

Я хочу запускать просто командой, вводить имя программы из любого места, типо

```
script
```

и всё)

Как это реализовать?

Comment: А в чём проблема, только что попробовал на Win7 + Node 4.4.3, вхожу в директорию где лежит js и запускаю его даже без расширения *.js

Comment: @vnn198 мне нужно из любого места системы запустить, как обычную консольную программу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В package.json я добавил

```
"preferGlobal": true,
"bin": {
  "script": "script.js"
 },
```

В начало файла script.js (точка входа)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Далее создал ссылку с помощью

```
npm link
```

И после этого мы можем запускать наш скрипт scriptпросто

```
script
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить путь в PATH

1. На рабочем столе правой кнопкой нажмите на значок Компьютер.
2. В контекстном меню выберите Свойства.
3. Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
4. Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе *Переменные среды* в подразделе *Системные переменные* выберите переменную среды *path* и в конце строки через **;** укажите путь к вашему скрипту.

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто :) я уже проверял, не работает

Comment: Должно работать, для примера кинь свой скрипт в папку которая прописана в path. Например я для пробы кинул скрипт в папку nodejs которая уже прописана в path, и всё заработало, к стати после прописывания нужно открывать новое окно cmd, ибо path инициализируется только при запуске cmd. И ещё, если в скрипте используются нестандартные модули то надо будет в самом скрипте прописывать полные пути к ним.

Answer (score 0):

Предположительно у Вас `Windows`.
У меня так:

1. Создан `.bat`, который выполняется при каждом старте `cmd`:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER
       [SOFTWARE]
           [Microsoft]
               [Command Processor]
                   (Autorun) = "%systemdrive%\path\to\file.bat"
   ```
2. Создание ссылок вида:

   ```
   doskey sudo = powershell %Tcmd%\ImplementationSudoCommand.ps1 $*
   ```

   Теперь в винде есть удобный способ запуска любой программы с повышенными правами: `sudo cmd`.

Comment: м, sudo в винде? у Вас видимо developer preview

Comment: @KoVadim, пихаю этот скрипт везде, удобно же - сидишь без особых прав, а повышать иногда надо. В винде это ад.

Comment: Да, нет `sudo` по умолчанию в Windows.

Comment: @Kirby, Вы проницательны :)